# Copying parameters of a layer in Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to take the last layer in a model (old model) and make a new model of only one layer (new model) that has the exact same parameters as the last layer of the old model.  I want to do this in a way that's agnostic to what the last layer of the old model happens to be.  I'm trying to do it with this code, but am getting an error.

```
newModel = Sequential()
newModel.add(type(oldModel.layers[-1])(oldModel.layers[-1].output_shape,
                                            activation=oldModel.layers[-1].activation,
                                            input_shape=oldModel.layers[-1].input_shape))
```

That yields the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output_dim'
```

If I check the last layer in oldModel, it shows me this:

```
full_model.model.layers[-1]
>>>> <keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7fe22010e128>
```

I tried adding output_dim to the list of parameters I'm copying in this way, but that didn't seem to help.  It gave me this error instead when I did that:

```
Exception: Input 0 is incompatible with layer dense_8: expected ndim=2, found ndim=3
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself.  If, instead of making the input_shape the same as the input_shape of the last layer of the old model, I make it the output_shape of the penultimate layer of the old model and specify only [1:] of that output array, it works.  Code that works is as follows:

```
newModel.add(type(oldModel.layers[-1])(oldModel.layers[-1].output_shape,
                                        activation=oldModel.layers[-1].activation,
                                        input_shape=oldModel.layers[-2].output_shape[1:]))
```